# struts2 - understanding the value stack

Tags: java, struts2, valuestack

I have a question regarding the struts2 value stack. Let's say I have an Action class called `RegisterAction` that has an execute method as follows:

```
public String execute() {
    ValueStack stack = ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack();
    stack.push(new String("test string"));
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

My struts.xml looks like this:

```
<struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*Register" method="{1}" class="vaannila.RegisterAction">
            <result name="populate">/register.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/register.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        </action>        
        <action name="*Test" method="{1}" class="vaannila.TestAction">
            <result name="test">/test.jsp</result>
            <result name="success">/success2.jsp</result>
        </action>        
    </package>
</struts>
```

So control will flow to the success.jsp after the execute method executes in that class.

My questions are:

1) how do I get that value I pushed on the stack in the `success.jsp`?

2) Let's say in `success.jsp` I have a `<s:submit method="testMethod" />` that redirects to an action class called `TestAction`. In other words, from the Register page, the user clicks submit, and in the execute method of the `RegisterAction` we push the "test string" on the stack. Then we go to `success.jsp`.  The `success.jsp` has a submit button that directs us to `TestAction#testMethod`. In `TestAction#testMethod`, is the value I pushed on the stack in `RegisterAction#execute` still there?  How can I get it? I stepped through the eclipse debugger but I don't see the value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.

1) The way I found to get objects on the value stack so we can access them from a jsp is like this:

```
Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();
context.put("key", "some object");
context.put("key2", "another object");
ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().push(context);
```

In other words, we can put a HashMap on the value stack containing the objects we need. Then, in the jsp, we can access the actual values like this:

```
<s:property value="key" />
<s:property value="key2" />
```

It will look through the value stack and find those values in the HashMap we pushed.

2)
An instance of the action class is associated with just one request. So when we go to another action and then end up at another jsp, the stuff we pushed on the value stack from the first action won't be there since the other action has it's own value stack.
reference: http://www.manning-sandbox.com/thread.jspa?messageID=93045

You guys can feel free to correct me if any of this is wrong or if there are smarter ways to do these things :).

Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't just setting a variable in action work with redirect params?

Answer (score 2):

Struts 2 adds your action to the top of the value stack when executed.  So, the usual way to put stuff on the Value Stack is to add getters/setters for the values to your Action class.  You still use the s:property tag to access the values.

A CRUD tutorial: http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/crud-demo-i.html

Answer (score 2):

just define a property like

```
String string1 = "test string";
```

in your action.

in jsp you can access directly.

e.g

```
 <s:property value="string1"/>
```

will print out

> "test string"

Answer (score 0):

Normally, as Nate says, you will use a field in your action, since the action is always on the ValueStack. However, this doesn't work if you're writing interceptor code since the interceptor will be gone by the time the template (JSP/freemarker etc) is invoked. There you need to put some kind of java bean-like object on the ValueStack, just as you do above.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just for information

These is a downside of using `getValueStack().getContext()` sometimes the data was not available in .ftl (data was not showing in line2, but it was coming in line1) i really dont know the reason for this. But using `.getValueStack().set("resDTO",resDTO);` the problem was solved (data was getting populated for both the functions).

```
 ${resDTO.data} //line 1
var selonload='<@s.property value="resDTO.data" escape="false" />'; //line 2
```